# Speeding up a pyautogui screenshot in a loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

So, I have this program over here that I will use to make a bot for the snake game. But it simply is way too slow. Any ideas on how to speed it up?

```
import pyautogui
running = True

color = (231, 71, 29)
while running == True:
    s = pyautogui.screenshot()
    for x in range(s.width):
        for y in range(s.height):
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
                pyautogui.click(x, y)
                s = pyautogui.screenshot()
                print(x, y)
```

Comment: You are clicking a __LOT__ on a colour and doing an expensive screen grab on every click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your screenshot area. According to [pyautogui's docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function):

> On a 1920 x 1080 screen, the `screenshot()` function takes roughly 100 milliseconds - it’s not fast but it’s not slow.
>
> There is also an optional `region` keyword argument, if you do not want a screenshot of the entire screen. You can pass a four-integer tuple of the left, top, width, and height of the region to capture:
>
> ```
> >> import pyautogui
> >> im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))
> ```

If you can define the screenshot region of only your snake game, it can be faster.